# Stream fusion in total functional language

Tags: functional-programming

As I understand, [stream fusion](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.104.7401) consists in converting operations on lists to operations on streams (colists), optimize redundant codata to data and back conversions, fuse operations on streams, and finally convert the resulting stream to a list again.

Data to codata conversion is a total operation, but the opposite is not. Is stream fusion optimization impossible in total functional programming languages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If all you have are are plain inductive and coinductive types, fusion is impossible, for the reason you point out.
2. However, it *is* possible if your type system supports *sized types*. These types let you track how big the elements of a type are. So you can use a coinductive representation, but instrument the type with size information, to guarantee that you can convert back to an inductive representation.

   A reasonably gentle introduction to these ideas is in Hughes, Pareto and Sabry's paper [*Proving the Correctness of Reactive Systems Using Sized Types*](https://www.cs.indiana.edu/%7Esabry/papers/reactive.ps), and they have also recently been  [implemented in Agda](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.2/language/sized-types.html).